# How to use attribute selector for span hover

Tags: css

I have the following unique attribute assigned to a class:

```
.subcategory1:hover span { background: url(entertainment-hover.png); }
```

I have many such subcategory classes and I want to assign them additionally general attributes for `:hover span` and I came up with the following:

```
[class*="subcategory"]:hover span {
  background-size: 20px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 2px;
```

But it doesn't work and I cant find the problem!

Does anyone know what I have to amend to make this work assigning these attributes to all subcategory classes on :hover for span?

Please note that I dont have access to the HTML Code!

EDIT

```css
[class*=subcategory]:hover span{
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 20px !important; 
  }
  
  
.subcategory1:hover span{ 
  background: url(https://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/designmodo-icon.png) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="subcategory1">
    <span style="font-size: 100px;">I am in a mess</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: [class*=subcategory] will fix it i guess!

Comment: I would suggest adding an additional class (say, "subcategory") to all of these elements so that you don't have to use an attribute selector.

Comment: Without seeing a relevant snippet of your HTML it's impossible to offer specific advice as to why your selector doesn't work, and thus this question is unanswerable. Please: post enough of your – [mcve] – HTML that will allow us to help you.

Comment: That's something that should be spelled out in the question!

Comment: Place don't deface your post. If you'd like to delete it, flag it for moderator attention, explaining why you'd like it deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class to the current classes that you want to add an effect on hovering it 
for example

```css
.hover-effect:hover span {
/*
your CSS code
*/
}
```

```html
<div class="subcategory1 hover-effect">
<span>text</span>
</div>
<div class="subcategory2 hover-effect">
<span>text</span>
</div>
<div class="subcategory3 hover-effect">
<span>text</span>
</div>
<div class="subcategory4 hover-effect">
<span>text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

> remove quotation from the class name in css file

```
[class*=subcategory]:hover span {
  background-size: 20px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 2px;
}
```

I made a  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7wormr5/1/) for you too.