# How can I use attribute selector for span hover

Tags: css

I have the following unique attribute assigned to a class:

```
.subcategory1:hover  span { background: url(entertainment-hover.png); }
```

I have many such subcategory classes and I want to assign them additionally general attributes for :hover span and I came up with the following:

```
 [class*=subcategory]:hover span {
 background-size: 20px; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0px 2px; }
```

But it doesn't work and I cant find the problem - please see snippet 1 below for an example of the problem and snippet 2 how it should look if the general attributes of class* where assigned correctly to subcategory1!

Does anyone know what I have to amend to make this work assigning these attributes to all subcategory classes on :hover for span?

*Please note that I dont have access to the HTML Code!*

**SNIPPET 1** The code and problem

```css
[class*=subcategory]:hover span{
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-size: 20px !important; 
}
  
  
.subcategory1:hover span{ 
background: url(https://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/designmodo-icon.png) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="subcategory1">
<span style="font-size: 100px;">I am in a mess</span>
</div>
```

**SNIPPET 2** how it should look (but doesnt in the above example)

```css
[class*=subcategory]:hover span{ }
        
.subcategory1:hover span{ 
background: url(https://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/designmodo-icon.png) !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-size: 20px !important;     
}
```

```html
<div class="subcategory1">
<span style="font-size: 100px;">I am in a mess</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The second snippet works for me. It looks like a weird use case though, can't you make all have the class subcategory?

Comment: @Axnyff the 2nd snippet is only how the 1st snippet result should look like, i.e background size of picture is only 20px. But I have many subcategories, that all require the same attributes, so snippet 2 is not a practical solution it's just a to clarify how the result of snippet 1 should look.

Comment: didn't you post the same question before ? :) looks familiar to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use attribute selector for span hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674677/how-to-use-attribute-selector-for-span-hover)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, but there was too much confusion because I didnt provide enough details and no body replied any more, so I wanted to provide a clear example eliminating any confusion. I tried deleting the old one but it didnt work and my edit in deleting everything got reverted. Bit frustrating. Good memory :-)

Comment: you should at least remove the old one ... we don't post same question simply because old one wasn't good

Comment: I tried to make everything clean by deleting the old one! I couldnt! I got an error message.

Comment: it's simple .. use background-image instead of background .. you are overriding properties

Comment: You should use your browser devtools, you would have seen that the properties are overriden

Comment: @TemaniAfif THANK YOU that's very helpful! It works!! Truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you use property "background" you override other rules.
Use instead "background-image".